# Trouble With Creating Random Job Assigner

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, variable-assignment

I am trying to create a random job assigner using Python. I want to assign a random list of names a random job. I do not want anyone to have the same job as anyone else either. I am making some head way on this script but I ran into a problem where one of the items of the jobs and people list are cut off. Below is my code and the output. All help and advice is appreciated thanks!

```
import random
jobs = ['scrub', 'wash', 'collect']
people = ['Tim', 'Ryan', 'Jon']
job_assignments = {}

def jobs_Create():
    for person in ppl:
        for job in jobs:
            selected_job = random.choice(jobs)
            job_assignments[person] = selected_job
            jobs.remove(selected_job)
    return job_assignments
```

Here is the output when I run the function:
{'Tim': 'scrub', 'Ryan': 'collect'}

Comment: Remove that line `for job in jobs:` and deindent the lines below it. Also ppl->people.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `random.choice()` you can use `random.sample()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample)):

```
import random

jobs = ['scrub', 'wash', 'collect']
people = ['Tim', 'Ryan', 'Jon']

job_assignments = dict(zip(people, random.sample(jobs, len(jobs))))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(job_assignments, width=30)
```

Prints (for example):

```
{'Jon': 'wash',
 'Ryan': 'collect',
 'Tim': 'scrub'}
```